# Can CFL bulbs in a fixture with a dimmer switch damage old wiring?

Tags: electrical, wiring, light-fixture, cfl

Our wiring is not functioning now after using a CFL bulb in a dimmable light fixture.  Is it possible that use of the CFL bulb could affect our old wiring?  We may have to replace the wire leading to this fixture.  Also other light fixtures on same wire are not working now.

Comment: What does this mean, "*Our wiring is not functioning*"?  Is the CFL not lighting up, did it ever?  Do other incandescent bulbs work?  Do you have a multimeter?

Answer (score 1):

Typically CFL's are not made for dimmers. You need to match a dimmable CFL with the right type of dimmer. It is possible that the CFL damaged your dimmer but not the wiring.

Answer (score 0):

It seems unlikely that the CFL itself would be able to cause damage to the wiring on its own. All the bulb knows how to do is draw current from what it's given. It seems like something else is afoot here. If your wiring is old (how old is old?) you must have managed to damage it some other way, either while installing the new bulbs or installing the dimmer switch, etc.

Comment: Dimmer switch already in place.  All we did was replace regular bulbs with CFL.  Could be wiring just needs to be replaced.  It could be very old.  House is 100yrs. old

Comment: Maybe just a coincidence this happened after we started using CFL bulbs